# Domain name in ASCII doc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Is there anything is ASCII doc where I can fetch the domain for the site. For example: if I am viewing the docs on example.com website then the doc should display HOST: example.com. If I am viewing on local instance then doc should display HOST: localhost:8443

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JavaScript` to extract the Host-Name, like

```
var host = window.location.host
```

And then you could set this value the JavaScript way, like

```
var hostDiv = document.getElementById('hostDiv');
hostDiv.innerHTML = host;
```

I use `docinfo-footer` for such snippets. See https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file